# Integrating Unity in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

Well, I have seen and tried most of tutorials referenced from similar questions "How to integrate Unity iOS code into Swift project". But all my attempts were failed with linker error "No such symbol for architecture arm_64" or "No such symbol for architecture x86_64". I have tried different build options in Unity side, no success.
Common minus of all of that tutorials / articles is: all of them outdated, latest version of Unity I have found article is 2018.2.2f1, my version of Unity is 2018.2.20f1.
So, anyone have idea how integrate Unity 2018.2.20+ iOS builded code into Swift 4.2 (XCode 10) project?
Any help will be great appreciated.

Comment: You can create Unity3D app, build it to iOS project, and where you need, you can push your new ViewController to root: `let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController as! YourViewController`. Don't forget to close/hide/pause unused controllers from Unity3D. You can communicate with Unity3D code via **PlayerPrefs = UserDefaults** interfaces. I already did several projects same way.

Comment: can you share some code examples please?

Comment: do you familiar with the PlayerPrefs? For example, when (say, on tap some button) you want to load a new ViewController from a Xcode Project (say, some scene), in Unity3D set a key "GoToXcode" to PlayerPrefs. And in Xcode class **AppDelegate** listen to UserDefaults: `let isChange = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “GoToXcode”) ?? false`. You can listen to it in Timer's block. `if isChange { let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController as! YourViewController}`.

Comment: I think I got your point. But you looking on Unity part as "main" (or controller) part of the project, in my case it's opposite, I have big Swift project where I want only in one case show user Unity 3D scene, so I want to have ability show that scene as some UnityViewController for example.

Comment: I think, it is possible in two ways: you should control Xcode and Unity3D AppDelegates. Unity3D AppDelegate is complex and have so many objects both Unity3D and custom methods. Good Luck.

Comment: Hi @zzheads,  I got the same architecture error. I try below solution but it's not working. can you please help me if you solve.
- https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity
- https://medium.com/@IronEqual/how-to-embed-a-unity-game-into-an-ios-native-swift-app-772a0b65c82

Comment: Sorry, did not solved it

Comment: @zzheads If my answer helpful could you please add bounty to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I have integrated unity in my swift project.

1. Create new Xcode project (using swift)
2. (create bridging header step) Create new class File -> New -> Cocoa touch class  and select language Objective C it will ask for create bridging header choose create
3. Goto https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity and download zip file
4. Open downloaded file  and unzip it. Go to Xcode folder -> DemoApp-> You will find **Unity Folder** copy paste to your project (if you drag and drop it make sure you check the check box for copy at destination)
5. open your new Xcode project and auto generated unity project side by side so you can copy paste it easily
6. copy **Classes Folder** from unity Xcode project to your Xcode project  to the **unity** Folder of step 4
7. copy **Library Folder**  from unity Xcode project to your Xcode project  to the **unity** Folder of step 4
8. copy **Data** Folder  from unity Xcode project to your Xcode project  to the **unity** Folder of step 4
9. ***Important*** Goto Xcode project tap on name of project on left side there will be two options **Project and target**. Select **project**  on centre main window you can see **Configuration** Expand it and against the name of your project choose **Unity** from drop drown
10. Goto  **Classes** Folder that you have copied in step
    And either delete **main.mm** file or comment everything
11. goto folder you have downloaded in step3 Copy all code of `AppDelegate.swift` to your `AppDelegate.swift` file
12. In your Xcode project search for **YourProjectFileName-Bridging-Header**  and copy paste

    #ifndef BRIDGING_HEADER
    #define BRIDGING_HEADER

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "UnityUtils.h"
    #import "UnityAppController.h"
    #import "UnityInterface.h"

    #endif /* BRIDGING_HEADER */
13. Copy paste **LaunchScreen-iPad.xib** and **LaunchScreen-iPhone.xib** to your project and delete ***LaunchScreen.storyboard***
14. **Compile it**  :] it should compile successfully (not in my case I got error that DeviceSettings.mm there is return statement missing so I just added return deviceUnknown;  before the })
15. You can see  step3 downloaded  view controller.swift file for see how to show unity view in your screen

Notes: After integrate unity you are not able to run in simulator so you have to run in real device.
it is better to have unity and xcode in same machine. sometime all the framework only get ref of folder so in different machine you may face the issue

at last your project should look like

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In my case "Exports.xcconfig"  file missing in "Unity.xcconfig" file.
when I will comment line *#include "Exports.xcconfig"* and try to run with steps provided from you it gives me below error. http://prnt.sc/nilcsl

I am follow step in xcode 10.2 and unity 2018.3.0f2

Comment: @DhavalPatel see this https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity/issues/8\

Comment: Hi, @Prashant Tukadiya I have checked above solution. "Exports.xcconfig" file generated automatically. but when I build a project with the above step it gives me an error. http://prnt.sc/nilcsl

Comment: @DhavalPatel Don't do it in simulator , You have to run the project in real device as it doesn't support simulator architecture

Comment: Hi, @Prashant in real device it gives me same error. please check https://prnt.sc/ninvwy

Comment: @DhavalPatel Did you build unity project first  it will generate Exports.xcconfig file? make sure you have added this file https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity/blob/master/XcodePostBuild.cs in unity project

Comment: in my case  "Exports.xcconfig"  file generated in a project specified in XcodePostBuild.cs file. Here is my screenshot of my project navigator. http://prnt.sc/nio3f4

Comment: @DhavalPatel Could you pleas show project setting screen shot. i mean  in configuration did you select unity ?. And is your bridging header is correct ?

Comment: @DhavalPatel it seems that you copy bridging header file also  ?. You have to create your own it should be TestUnity-Bridging-Header.h something like **see step2**

Comment: check project configuration and bridging header screen shot. http://prnt.sc/nioav7, http://prnt.sc/nioavi

Comment: @DhavalPatel And your bridging header file has everything in step12 ?

Comment: @DhavalPatel Data folder must must add as folder ref. Remove it from xcode move to trash . . again drag and drop Data folder  into xcode and select create folder ref. for that

Comment: I already add code in bridging file. http://prnt.sc/niog0p. Can you please share me working sample.

Comment: i am removing Data folder and add reference it said multiple machine.config for mono version 2.0 and 4.0

Comment: @DhavalPatel Okay, Goto Unity --> Open project --> Goto Player setting --> change scriptable backhand to **LL2CPP**  not **mono** again follow step from 1 to 13 with new generated xcode project

Comment: @DhavalPatel One more thing. While exporting unity project for iOS make sure you have selected **symlink unity library check box**